# How to program NVDA read text field and button text in Swing Form

Tags: java, swing, nvda

[image: Number addition swing application]

Hello All,
I am trying to make swing application accessible to visually impaired people. I have designed Form using Swing components but I could not make NVDA read my textfield and button's text.

Things I have done are: 
1. Configured Java Access Bridge
2. Implemented Accessible interface
[image]

How can I make NVDA work ? 
Thanks in advance.